# query syntax error CakePHP 1.3

Tags: mysql, cakephp-1.3

My CakePHP version is 1.3.16. The CakePHP project was written in version 1.3 but I don't know exact version. MySQL version is 5.6.

I am getting syntax error in a query that is made this way.

```
$record = $this->$model->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array($model.'.p_id' => $currPid),
//          'fields' => $fields,
//          'recursive' => -1,
            'limit'=>$limit));
```

The query is very long; the part with the error is in code below. There are many other left joins with aliases in that query that work fine.

I think problem is `discontinue_med` outside the backtick (``) marks.

```
LEFT JOIN 'yn' AS 'DiscontinueMed' ON (`Enr`.`discontinue_med` = `DiscontinueMed`.`id`)
```

How can this be fixed ?

Comment: Will you post the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

Should be inside backticks, or I miss something here.

```
... ON (`Enr`.`discontinue_med` = `DiscontinueMed`.`id`)
```

Comment: Yes. For some reason the query comes out with the discontinue_med outside the backticks.It's made by the CakePHP find() function in the 1st piece of code shown above.

Comment: Is there a way to explicitly write a query and run it ?

Comment: Yes, that's what helped find the error. Think it's fixed though.